# Spring Boot requestDataValueProcessor Bean Definition Conflict

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I try to use `SpringWebFluxSecurity`in my project, but I got this error when compiling

`The bean 'requestDataValueProcessor', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/reactive/WebFluxSecurityConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.`

I know that I have to remove the dependency to `WebMvcSecurityConfiguration`. The problem is I cannot figure out where that configuration is being called in my project. Do you have any idea how to find it?

Comment: Could you attach pom.xml  with spring dependencies and your main class?

Comment: I already solved this problem. It turns out that I just need to specify spring.main.web-application-type inside `application.yml`. So, I add this `spring.main.web-application-type: reactive`

Answer (score 2):

Run a `mvn dependence:tree and you'll be able to see the dependence tree of your project. Then try to find out which are the packages of this dependencies and removes that you don't need.